my app started encountering weird errors all of a sudden
I started getting the weird error output below in my Metro console.  I think it may have happened after I did npm install react-native-swipe-list-view:
===
error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native from C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\@react-native\virtualized-lists\Interaction\Batchinator.js: react-native could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | const {InteractionManager} = require('react-native');
     |                                       ^
  14 |
  15 | /**
  16 |  * A simple class for batching up invocations of a low-pri callback. A timeout is set to run the
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:138:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at resolveDependencies (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
    at visit (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async buildSubgraph (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:103:3)
    at async Graph._buildDelta (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:157:22)
    at async Graph.traverseDependencies (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:49:19)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:187:42)
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

^^^ This is weird bc the error is coming from within the @react-native package in node_modules.  I did an uninstall of react-native-swipe-list-view, Wiped Data from my Android emulator and even deleted node_modules.  Now I get a different error:
error: Error: Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault from C:\CODE\MediaManager\index.js: @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
> 1 | /**
    | ^
  2 |  * @format
  3 |  */
  4 |
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:138:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at resolveDependencies (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
    at visit (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async buildSubgraph (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:103:3)
    at async Graph._buildDelta (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:157:22)
    at async Graph.traverseDependencies (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:49:19)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (C:\CODE\MediaManager\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:187:42)

^^^ This seems pretty strange.  Any idea what the issue might be, next steps to debug, etc?  I can't say that I've seen behavior like this pop up all of a sudden - but I'm guessing that someone here must have a guess.
